# protractor how to select the radio buttons for a non-angular site

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I want to select the second radio button on an E2E testing for a non angular site. How can I select the radio button ?

```
<blockquote>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="id" value="jo" onclick="form.submit(); return false;”>radio 1
        </label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="id" value="go" onclick="form.submit(); return false;" checked=“”>radio 2
        </label>
        <i>(some extra test)</i>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="id" value="jw" onclick="form.submit(); return false;”>radio 3
        </label>
        <br>
        <br>
    </blockquote>
```

I have tried this

```
var rB browser.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@value='go']")); 
but
 rB.click() says
 Message: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'click' Stacktrace: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'click' at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/spec/example_spec.js:53:11) ==== async task ==== Asynchronous test function: it() Error at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Library/WebServer/Documents/youman/test/spec/spec/example_spec.js:49:4) at Object.<anonymous> –
```

Comment: What if you try `findElement()` instead of `findElements()`?

Answer (score 0):

As per [alexce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe), use findElement() instead of findElement**s**()